# How To Change Keyword to Numeric in Elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

Hello I have an error about Rails Elasticsearch with `searchkick gem`

the error

```
Searchkick::InvalidQueryError ([400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Expected numeric type on field [item_final_price], but got [keyword]"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"items_development_20180507023923980","node":"w7LqCILTTK-gndnoQB1cOQ","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Expected numeric type on field [item_final_price], but got [keyword]"}}]},"status":400}):
```

Basically telling me the error is **expecting numeric type but the type is keywords**

heres my search params

in  controller.rb

```
def results
    price_ranges = [{to: params[:max_price]}, {from: params[:min_price], to: params[:max_price]}, {from: params[:min_price]}]
    @results = Item.search(params[:q], aggs: {item_final_price: {ranges: price_ranges}}, page: params[:page], per_page: 10) if params[:q].present?
end
```

my views

```
<%= form_tag results_path, method: :get, enforce_utf8: false, id: "q_filter" do %>
<section class="widget widget-categories">
    <%= hidden_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
    <h3 class="widget-title">Price Range</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Price Between</label>
        <%= number_field_tag :min_price, params[:min_price].to_f, class: "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder: "Min Price" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>And</label>
        <%= number_field_tag :max_price, params[:max_price].to_f, class: "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder: "Max Price" %>
    </div>
    <%= button_tag(type: "submit", name: nil, class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block") do %>
        Filter Search
    <% end %>
</section>
```

and my model

```
include Elasticsearch::Model
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
Item.import

searchkick callbacks: :async

def search_data
    {
        item_name: item_name,
        item_details: item_details,
        item_final_price: item_final_price
    }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my Answer. What I did is change the column datatype from **string** to **float.**